# nav menu not functioning correctly

Tags: css, html

Ok, I'm working on this website (its my first one), and I am looking for some insight on making my nav menu work better.  When you go to the "projects" page, the about button all of a sudden looks like it has too much spacing to the right.  Also, when you go to the "Contact" page, the menu is totally messed up.  I thought about just adding the home button to the main page navigation so all the menus would be exactly the same and maybe it would work right, but there HAS to be a better solution.

Also, the website looks really flat.  I'd be open to suggestions on giving it some depth, as well as any other criticism you may have.  (bear in mind I've only been doing this for a couple months).

[**Web address**](http://s423839726.onlinehome.us/index2.html)

**HTML:**

```
 <ul class="transparent" id="navcontainer" >        
    <li class="topnavleft floatleft"><a href="index2.html">Home</a></li>                    
    <li class="topnav floatleft"><a href="About.html">About</a></li>                           
    <li class="topnavright floatleft"><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>                    
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#navcontainer {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 55px;
    width: 232px;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.topnav {
    width: 45px;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.topnavleft {
    width: 45px;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

.topnavright {
    width: 45px;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-right: 7px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

Comment: should i be able to do this with just one "topnav" class?  Also, i've started trying to implement what you are saying, and i think it might work, but the problem i'm seeing now is that when you hover on the links the entire div changes size and the links next to it move.  I'd like for them to be completely stationary.  any ideas?

Comment: that was supposed to be in response to @Victor S.

Comment: [Check the W3C validation result](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fs423839726.onlinehome.us%2Findex2.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Fix all errors and warnings there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with this line in the About page:

```html
<div class="transparent" id="logo"><a href="www.ALRGuitars.com"><img src="Images/ALR%20%20custom%20guitars2.png" alt="ALR Custom Guitars" width="250" border="0" </a></img>
```

You have missed out the closing `/>` of the `img` tag, it should be like this:

```html
<div class="transparent" id="logo"><a href="http://www.alrguitars.com"><img src="Images/ALR%20%20custom%20guitars2.png" alt="ALR Custom Guitars" width="250" border="0" /></a></img>
```

For screenreaders and search engines, the logo should have the text `ALR Custom Guitars`, use a `background-image` instead of an `img` tag, and set `text-indent: -999px` so that only the image will show.

Also, lots of your links point to `www.ALRGuitars.com`, they should be `http://www.ALRGuitars.com`.

---

**EDIT:**

Here are some errors to correct (remember to correct *all* errors and warnings from [the W3C validation result](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fs423839726.onlinehome.us%2Findex2.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)):

This:

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/ALR-Guitars/301363959926689" target="_blank"><img src="Images/facebook_512.png" border="0" height="32px" width="32px" </img><a/>
<a href="http://twitter.com/ALRGuitars" target="_blank"><img src="Images/twitter_512.png" border="0" height="32px" width="32px"</img></a>
```

Should be:

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/ALR-Guitars/301363959926689" target="_blank"><img src="Images/facebook_512.png" border="0" height="32px" width="32px" />
<a href="http://twitter.com/ALRGuitars" target="_blank"><img src="Images/twitter_512.png" border="0" height="32px" width="32px"</img></a>
```

In the copyright notice, you have forgotten a semicolon after a character reference.

Either use `&#169;` or `&copy;`.

This:

```
<link href'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Over+the+Rainbow|Open+Sans:600,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Should be:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Over+the+Rainbow|Open+Sans:600,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

There was a missing `=` sign after `href`.

---

**EDIT #2:**

After some fiddling with the CSS, try this for the menu:

```css
#navcontainer {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
.topnav a {
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
a:hover {
    color: #606060;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

It should correct the problem of the links moving when hovered over.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! that is SO helpful!  trying to teach myself all this stuff isn't easy...you just don't know what you dont know, as the old adage goes.  any idea how i can get the div's in the nav menu not to shift when an adjacent link is hovered over?  I'd like them to just stay still.

Comment: @user1476992 Try using `float: left` instead of `display: inline` for the menu `li`s. Also, the main `navcontainer` `ul` doesn't need `display: inline` on it, it has no effect. (By the way, removing empty links would clean up your markup.)

Comment: thank you!! i just made all your recommended changes, and its looking much better already.  What are you referring to when you say "empty links"?  Also, still trying to get my li div's not to shift when you hover over them...any ideas?

Comment: Empty links: `<a href="www.ALRGuitars.com"></a>`.

Comment: i must be missing some.  I tried to use CTRL+F to find any that were missing the http:// and added it to them.  I'll check again.

Comment: @user1476992 - About the menu - try removing the `padding` from `.topnav` and moving it to `.topnav li`, and add `display: block` to `.topnav li` so that the `width` from `.topnav li` will take effect.

Comment: You're welcome.  :-)  A few more things: Remember to correct the bug on your contact page (see the `link href` code under the heading `EDIT`), and correct validation errors. For the logo, put a link inside `#logo` and then change the style from `#logo {` to `#logo a`.

Comment: will do!  i got a bunch of errors corrected already, but it seems the remaining errors (At least on the index2.html page) are related to the facebook plug-in, possibly because of my doctype?  I don't know much about doctypes, but i tried to experiment with them to try to fix the errors, but no luck.

Comment: Try the HTML5 doctype (the newest one): `<!DOCTYPE html>`. It's also the simplest one, and even triggers Standards Compliance Mode in IE6.

Comment: One error (that causes a few more) is that `<div id="fb-root"></div>` is in the head section of the page, move it underneath `<body>`. Another one is all of the `data-` attributes, they are HTML5 only, so changing the doctype will fix most of the errors. Another is the `<script>` tag, you need to specify a type, so change it to `<script type="text/javascript">`. The warning means there is a byte-order-mark in the source, try removing that.

Comment: ... (about the BOM) You won't be able to see it, install a good editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) and make the document ANSI-encoded. It will turn into a question mark that you can then remove.

Comment: WOOHOO!!! <http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fs423839726.onlinehome.us%2Findex2.html;st=1>

Comment: That's great! To get rid of the warnings, just insert `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` after `<head>`. P.S. - please upvote and accept my answer if your problem is solved. :-)

Comment: Okay, you have 18 reputation now :-)

Answer (score 0):

the spacing is because you specified topnav width as 45...'projects' is too large and 'about' is too small..let it be automatic or try to align all the text into the middle so that it wont seem weird...